# Suggestion about Minhash implementation with n permutation

Tags: python, matrix, dataset, bigdata, data-mining

I'm trying to understand LSH implementation. I found this on stackoverflow

[Can you suggest a good minhash implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14533420/can-you-suggest-a-good-minhash-implementation)

and I try to follow the Duhaime's implementation.

In my case, i wish apply a permutation on the minhash(like in datasketch tool), and i think this implementation isn't good for me.
I already start from sparse matrix.

Someone can give some suggestion about this tecnique? isn't very diffuse so i don't find more material about implementation with Python.

I hope in you help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't just look for example code. Try to understand the math behind it.

Obviously, maxhash should work similar. Or you could omit 0 values. But then you should double check the math.